# Java Mail : PDF attachment not working

Tags: java, pdf, jakarta-mail

Ihave string which i need to send as a PDF attachment to mail, my code is as follows

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom("");
message.setRecipients("") 

message.setSubject("Test");

String example = "PDF Content";
byte[] pdf = example.getBytes();

MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource src = new ByteArrayDataSource(pdf, "application/pdf"); 

Multipart mp1 = new MimeMultipart();
attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(src));
attachment.setFileName("sample.pdf");
mp1.addBodyPart(attachment);
message.setContent(mp1);
Transport.send(message);
```

I'm getting pdf document as a attachment, but it not loading. please guide me to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are sending a byte array containing text "PDF content" as attachment. Your PDF reader definitively can not open this content as PDF. Try to send real PDF instead.

Comment: You may have to call the MimeMessage's saveChanges method.

Answer (score 2):

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom("");  // hopefully you're putting a real value here
message.setRecipients("");  // and here

message.setSubject("Test");

MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
Multipart mp1 = new MimeMultipart();
attachment.attachFile("sample.pdf", "application/pdf", "base64");
mp1.addBodyPart(attachment);
message.setContent(mp1);
Transport.send(message);
```

The [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html) has more sample code, and you'll find complete sample applications on the [JavaMail web site](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).